# Azure Storage Count Transactions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

Can you please explain what is the best way to estimate the transactions number on windows azure storage using the development environment? I though about implementing an int variable and increment that ex: i++ each time I make a call to azure storage? What do you think? Have you done such thing before? I just need to have an estimated amount of transactions ...

Answer (score 2):

there's the Windows Azure Storage Services REST API which you can use, it contains a a full API stack for Storage Analytics: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh343270.aspx. hope this helps (of course you can use the native monitoring through the portal also for starters)

Comment: Just to add a drop to this: Look specifically at the **`TotalBillableTransactions`** column of the `MetricsTransactionsBlob`, `MetricsTransactionsTable`, and `MetricsTransactionsQueue` tables.

Answer (score 1):

@techmike2kx gave you the REST API info. Instead, let me address your other question regarding the use of a local transaction counter. That approach won't really help you at all, for a few reasons:

- If you have multiple instances of your app running (e.g. 2 web role instances), you'd need a single counter across instances, which means you're now synchronizing, or you're accumulating numbers somewhere. And... you'll probably store these instance-specific counters in something like table storage, which will result in additional transactions.
- What if you use an attached disk with your VM? There will be transactions generated since the vhd is stored in a blob. You'll have no visibility into those transactions.
- Your storage account could be used by multiple apps. How will you track that?
- Your storage account could be used for logging and diagnostics, which you don't have much control over, regarding how those calls are made.
- You'll need to track unsuccessful transactions since these are not billed (these are documented).
- Some calls make multiple storage transactions. For instance: If you query table storage, and exceed what can be returned in a single transaction, you'll end up with multiple calls to storage, under the hood (hidden by the language-specific SDK you're using).
- What happens when you serve web content directly from  blobs (e.g. http://mysite.blob.core.windows.net/images/logo.jpg)? You'd have no control over this access, so no way to track it
- when will you roll your counter back to zero? How will you know the exact month-end of your billing cycle?

I'm sure there are other gotchas, but the bottom line is: You shouldn't be trying to track transaction consumption, since it's given to you via storage analytics.